# SQL change column data type with lots of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains millions of records.

I'm altering one column data type to another (money to decimal)

Noticing that is taking alot of time executing the alter statement. Probably due to the fact that there is alot of data.

Is there a way to increase the performance for this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All millions of rows have to changed at the same time in one transaction

Another option is to create a new table, insert in batches, drop old table, rename new table.
However, it's liable to take longer this way.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to create a temporary table with the new column type, copy the data from the original table to the temp, drop the original, and then rename the temp.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tmp_MyTable 
   (ID Integer, Name varchar (100), MyChangedField decimal (8,2))

INSERT INTO dbo.tmp_MyTable SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable

EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.tmp_MyTable', N'MyTable', 'OBJECT'
```

Keep in mind, this is an overly simple example.  If your original table has indexes, keys, and/or default values, you'll have to handle them as well.

One easy trick is to make the change in the SQL Server Management Studio table designer and generate the change script to see everthing that needs to be done.

Comment: I'd do a batched shift of data to minimise the size of each individual write. Of course, there is no benefit if it's still a single transaction.

Comment: In this case one should use a SELECT INTO statement as it will do less logging than an INSERT and therefore be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Would there be any time benefit in adding the new decimal column to the table, populating it from the money column in multiple batches using a CAST(), and when all is done, dropping the money column?